# How to test recapcha with rspecs on the devise sign_in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, recaptcha

For example, I have the following code:

```
context '#update_password' do
  it 'current_user can update his password' do
    user = FactoryBot.create :user

    sign_in user

    put :update_password, xhr: true, params: {
      id: user.id,
      user: {
        id: user.id,
        current_password: user.password,
        password: 'ValidPass1!'
      }
    }
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
```

How can I write a rspec test to verify the recapcha validness on sign_in ?

P.S. I am using `gem 'recaptcha', require: 'recaptcha/rails'`

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this:

```
context '#update_password' do
  it 'current_user can update his password' do
    user = FactoryBot.create :user
    allow(controller).to receive(:verify_recaptcha).and_return(true)
    sign_in user

    put :update_password, xhr: true, params: {
      id: user.id,
      user: {
        id: user.id,
        current_password: user.password,
        password: 'ValidPass1!'
      }
    }
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
```